# a lemma for Lebesgue outer measure

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

An interval in $\mathbb{R}$ can be either open, closed, or half closed, $l(I)= b-a$ where $b, a,\ (a<b)$ are exactly the boundaries of $I$.
The following lemma is important in order to prove the countable subadditivity of the Lebesgue outer measure;

Let $(I_m)$ and $(J_n)$ be sequences of intervals such that the $I_m$'s are pairwise disjoint, prove for $k,\ p$ arbitrary in $\mathbb{N}$, that $\bigcup\limits_{m=1}^k I_m\subseteq \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^p J_n$ implies $\sum\limits_{m=1}^kl(I_m)\leq \sum\limits_{n=1}^pl(J_n)$

Comment: Please add [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/592278), otherwise your question will likely be closed. Relevant context here includes all the definitions involved and what you have tried.

Comment: In particular, what is one allowed to assume?  If one knows that intervals are measureable, then this becomes trivial, but of course you don't want to assume that.

Comment: I edited the question, it asks to prove this without assuming anything about measures as it concerns the beginning of the construction of Lebesgue outer measure!
I have proven it, but I am looking for a more elegant proof !

Comment: You should describe your proof, optionally in an answer if it is too long to give in the question itself, so that we can see what you are hoping to improve.

Answer (score 1):

We prove this by mathematical induction on $k$, considering the proposition :

$P(k):$ $\quad$ for any $p$ in $\mathbb{N}$, if $I_m$'s are pairwise disjoint intervals such that $\bigcup\limits_{m=1}^k I_m\subseteq \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^p J_n$ then $\sum\limits_{m=1}^kl(I_m)\leq \sum\limits_{n=1}^pl(J_n)$

- Clearly $P(1)$ holds; if $I_1\subseteq \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^p J_n$ then we can show by induction on $p$ that $l(I_1)\leq \sum\limits_{n=1}^pl(J_n)$
- Suppose $P(k)$ holds, we want to prove $P(k+1)$, we will use induction on $p$;

Clearly for $p=1$, if $I_m$'s are pairwise disjoint intervals such that $\bigcup\limits_{m=1}^{k+1} I_m\subseteq J_1$ then $\sum\limits_{m=1}^{k+1}l(I_m)\leq l(J_1)$

Suppose now that the implication holds for a number $p$ of intervals $J_n$'s, and let $\{I_m\}_{m=1}^{k+1}$ be pairwise disjoint intervals such that $\bigcup\limits_{m=1}^{k+1} I_m\subseteq \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{p+1} J_n$ 
We want to prove that $\sum\limits_{m=1}^{k+1}l(I_m)\leq \sum\limits_{n=1}^{p+1}l(J_n)$ so to show that $P(k+1)$ holds and we will be done.

If one of the $p+1$ intervals $J_n$'s doesn't contain any point from any interval $I_m$, name it $J_{n_0}$, then obviously $\bigcup\limits_{m=1}^{k+1} I_m\subseteq \bigcup\limits_{n=1, n\neq n_0}^{p+1} J_n$ and by the hypothesis $\sum\limits_{m=1}^{k+1}l(I_m)\leq \sum\limits_{n=1, n\neq n_0}^{p+1}l(J_n) \leq \sum\limits_{n=1}^{p+1}l(J_n)$,

So we can assume that each interval of the $J_n$'s intersect with at least one of the $I_m$'s, 
we can discuss two cases here:

- In the case where there exists one $J_{n_1}$ that contains a whole interval $I_{m_1}$, we can have $k$ intervals $\{I_m\}_{m=1, m\neq m_1}^{k+1}$ contained in $\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{p+1} J_n$ so by the first induction hypothesis $$\sum\limits_{m=1, m\neq m_1}^{k+1}l(I_m)\leq \sum\limits_{n=1}^{p+1}l(J_n)$$ but also we know that this covering contain the interval $J_{n_1}$ with length exceeding the total length of the $I_m$'s by a quantity greater or equal to $l(I_{m_1})$, recall that the $I_m$'s are pairwise disjoint, so we can add this length without losing the inequality :
  $l(I_{m_1})+ \sum\limits_{m=1, m\neq m_1}^{k+1}l(I_m)\leq \sum\limits_{n=1}^{p+1}l(J_n)$, in that case then we have verified the needed.
- In the other case, when there is no interval from $(J_n)$ that contains a whole interval $I_m$, this means each interval $I_m$ is covered by at least two intervals from $(J_n)$, recall again that the $I_m$'s are pairwise disjoint, so necessarily in this case $p+1> k+1$, we can consider now the interval $I_{m_{LE}}$ that is the most 'at the left' (considering simply the interval that contain a real number lesser than all numbers in the other intervals), Notice that this interval is covered partially by $J_{n_{LE}}$ such that also this $J_{n_{LE}}$ cover no other interval, we can then have $k$ intervals $\{I_m\}_{m=1, m\neq m_{LE}}^{k+1}$ contained in $\bigcup\limits_{n=1, n\neq n_{LE}}^{p+1} J_n$ so by the first induction hypothesis $$\sum\limits_{m=1, m\neq m_{LE}}^{k+1}l(I_m)\leq \sum\limits_{n=1, n\neq n_{LE}}^{p+1}l(J_n)$$
  but also here we have for one part of the interval $I_{m_{LE}}$: $l(I_{m_{LE}}\cap J_{n_{LE}})\leq l(J_{n_{LE}})$,
  the other remaining part has length that is already in the 'excess' of the total length $\sum\limits_{n=1, n\neq n_{LE}}^{p+1}l(J_n)$, Thus $\sum\limits_{m=1}^{k+1}l(I_m)\leq \sum\limits_{n=1}^{p+1}l(J_n)$. QED

Comment: I wonder if we can have a shorter proof.

Answer (score 1):

There is a shorter proof that involves counting. If you were on a finely graded line, the length of a segment would be proportional to the number of gradations in the segment
$$l(I) \approx n(I) \cdot \Delta$$
where $\Delta$ is the distance between the points of the gradation. If we think a little about it, we have the estimates
$$(n(I)-1) \Delta \le l(I) < (n(I)+1) \Delta$$
from where we get
$$\frac{l(I)}{\Delta} -1 < n(I)\le \frac{l(I)}{\Delta}+1$$

Now, if the family of disjoint segments is contained in the union of $J_1$,$\ldots$ $J_p$ then we have

$$\sum n(I_m) \le \sum n(J_n)$$
just be counting . Applying the previous estimates for $n(I)$ we get
$$\sum (\frac{l(I_m)}{\Delta} -1) < \sum(\frac{l(J_n)}{\Delta}+1)$$
that is
$$\sum l(I_m) < \sum l(J_n) + \Delta\cdot (p-k)$$
Now take $\Delta\to 0$ and get the required inequality.

You can give a similar argument in higher dimensions, but one has to be a bit more careful with the estimates for number of lattice points.

One objection to the above argument is that it uses the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is archimedean. In fact, it the statement is really purely combinatorial, and so, it should be valid for totally ordered abelian groups.